# Trouble Inserting An Array of Information into a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, arrays, insert

I am having an issue with inserting an array of information into a mysql database. Basically I built a sortable gallery similar to Facebook's photo albums that can be arranged by moving the div to a new spot with jquery's sortable function.

I am using Ajax to call a php file which will inser the new order of the div's into the DB. The information is being passed correctly, it is just not being inserted correctly.

**The error I am receiving is:**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1

**The Php code is:**

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) {
    if ($item >= 1) {
        $sql[] = "UPDATE table SET order = '{$position}' WHERE id = '{$item}'";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**If I remove the mysql_query function and just do a print_r, I get:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => UPDATE table SET order = '0' WHERE id = '2'
    [1] => UPDATE table SET order = '1' WHERE id = '4'
    [2] => UPDATE table SET order = '2' WHERE id = '3'
    [3] => UPDATE table SET order = '3' WHERE id = '1'
    [4] => UPDATE table SET order = '4' WHERE id = '5'
    [5] => UPDATE table SET order = '5' WHERE id = '6'
)
```

This is the first time I have tried to do something like this. Any help would be great.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In `mysql_query($sql)` `$sql` is an array, therefore it's value is simply `Array`.  When you assign `$sql[] = "UPDATE table SET order = '{$position}' WHERE id = '{$item}'";` simply make this line `$sql = "UPDATE table SET order = '{$position}' WHERE id = '{$item}'";`.  That should solve your problem.

EDIT:

You can leave the `[]` and simply remove the `mysql_query` from where it is.  After your foreach list item, add this:

```
foreach($sql as $query) {
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: That works, but is now only updating one row. Since by moving a box, the order of all the positions change and if I have 6 boxes, there should be 6 sql updates to update all the rows for their new position number.<br/><br/>The response I get is:<br/>UPDATE table SET order = '5' WHERE id = '6'<br/>No matter which box I move around. I have 6 in total right now but more eventually will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is some confusion about what the [] operator does. You use [] when you want to append an element to the end of an existing array.

For example:

```
 $sql = array();
 $sql[] = 'UPDATE table SET order = "0" WHERE id = "2"';
 mysql_query($sql); // this will produce the error you are seeing
```

Versus:

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE table SET order = "0" WHERE id = "2"';
 mysql_query($sql); // this will work
```

You should rewrite your code as such:

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) {
  if ($item >= 1) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET order = '{$position}' WHERE id = '{$item}'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

That will do what you are intending. However, this is still not a good idea, since you are passing untrusted $_GET data directly to the database. I could, for example, call your script with a string like:

```
http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php?listItem=1'%3B%20DROP%20TABLE%20yourtable%3B
```

Since the value of `listItem` is going directly to the database -- and the `$item >= 1` check is insufficient, since PHP will evaluate a string as an integer if it begins with numeric data -- all I have to do is add a single quote to terminate the previous query, and I am then free to inject whatever SQL command I'd like; this is a basic SQL injection attack. Whenever you write database-touching code, you should cleanse any input that might be going to the database. A final version of your code might look like:

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) {

  if ($item >= 1) { // this check may or may not be needed depending on its purpose

    $sql = 'UPDATE table SET order = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($position) . '" WHERE id = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($item) . '"';
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  }

}
```

There are other ways to cleanse input data as well, that is just one of them. Hope that helps.